# Opening font files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, fonts, ios-simulator

I have a problem with opening font files (`*.ttf`) on iPhone device. These files are stored in directory that is named `fonts`. System call *open(2)* exits with error number 2.

We have many files in our project, that are open without problem. Only font files fail.

The iPhone simulator opens font files correctly. Problem is only on device (iPhone4).

In project we use c++.

Do you have any idea what can cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was caused by case sensitive behaviour of iPhone device. There is difference between iPhone simulator (that is case insensitive) and **iPhone device** (that is **case sensitive**).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my project. This is Objective-C opening an OTF type font. Not sure if it will work with .ttf but worth a try:

```
    // Load fonts
    NSString *fontPathLTStd = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TradeGothicLTStd" ofType:@"otf"];
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProviderLTStd = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([fontPathLTStd UTF8String]);
    tradeGothicLTStdFontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProviderLTStd);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProviderLTStd);
```

Comment: OP needs to read the content of the font files, not create fonts.